# ADB2C ROPC flow in Net Framework in C#

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, ropc

Is there an equivalent of AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword in .NET Framework 4.6.1? I am trying to implement ROPC flow to AD B2C "local" user account, but the docs for this class say that it's only applicable for .NET Core. Although, it does let me use it in the code, but it doesn't work. I followed all of the instructions, but still getting permission errors. I am wondering if it's my setup issues or the framework.

Unfortunately, we are stuck with the old framework for now.

Comment: AAD B2C doesn’t support server side ROPC, you’ll get throttled. You should avoid this approach. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is for legacy Mobile applications that can't change their UI. I am aware that it's not recommended, but I still need to get it done as a temporary solution until we phase out that app. If it's not supported then why is there an API? And many posts online from people who got it working in .net core?

Comment: The /token endpoint for ROPC is for public clients, who all have unique IPs. [Limitations of ROPC in B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#ropc-flow-notes). MSAL .net library reference has a [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication), it states supported for .net desktop and .net core, but not on UWP. You have to instantiate a `publicClient`.

Comment: So in a case described here it was working in Postman. This is what I am looking for.  The code within API would send a request with user name and password to B2C app registration. https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/resource-owner-password-flow-in-azure-ad-b2c-b9c71bb76323

Comment: Are you saying it can only be called from a browser? Is there a workaround? For example, calling into underlying Azure AD?

Comment: For B2C ROPC, you are at danger of being throttled if you call from a web server (6000req/5min/IP). Hence, as per the doc, it’s only supported for public clients (mobile). You can use the underlying AAD, but then you will not be issued a B2C token, but an AAD token. The claim sets, configurability of claims and issuer will differ. Why not add ROPC with MSAL into the legacy mobile app instead?

Comment: The Mobile app cant make any changes. If they could, we would just use Authorization Code Flow. We dont need a token in this legacy case. All we need is to verify credentials. Do you have a sample on how to call underlying AAD?

Comment: Can we call B2C's underlying Azure AD? Not the external IDP?